# Run Error 2465 cn't find field

Tags: ms-access-2010

run error 2465 Microsoft Access can’t find the field’First Name’ referred to in your expression. This is in Office 10 My field names have spaces between the words I tried changing it to 'First_Name and still getting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the expression which references that field.

Comment: .Body = "SSN: " & Forms!frmAccession!SSN & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Employee Name: " & Forms!frmAccession!First_Name & " " & Forms!frmAccession!Middle_Name & " " & Forms!frmAccession!Last_Name & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Prior Service Elevated: " & Forms!frmAccession!Civilian_Elevated_to_Spec & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Thank You." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        '& Forms![user info]![First_Name]
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh

Comment: With the *frmAccession* form open, go to the Immediate window.  (Ctrl+g will take you there.)  Copy this highlighted text, paste it into a blank line in the Immediate window and press Enter: `Debug.Print Forms!frmAccession![First Name]`  Does that show you the correct value?

Comment: copy what highlighted text?

Comment: `Debug.Print Forms!frmAccession![First Name]`

Comment: MIGUEL is what came up

Comment: Great!  That means `Forms!frmAccession![First Name]` is valid (avoids error #2465), which makes sense since you said the names contain spaces.  Perhaps you need to change the others, too?  `[Last Name]` instead of `Last_Name` ... and so forth.

Comment: That worked thank you